# SSIS - REST API - Send data

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to send data from SQL database to REST API using SSIS.

### Background:

The REST API takes 3 parameters as input and this input is supplied via output from a sql query which will return me 10 records from my database. 
I have a web service with the help of a method in it performs specific task. Once the tasks are complete it gives an output of ID.

### So far:

what I have done is built a package having Execute SQL task to generate the 10 records, followed by the Foreach Loop Container passing the 10 records to loop which contains the Script Task to connect to the Webservice. Further if Web Service is successful I will use the output to update a table with the ID for the 10 records.

My Question is:
How to get the result of the SQL query and input it to the REST API? I want to make this possible for one record for now. If this works then I will loop the 10 records.

Regards,
KK

Comment: Instead of using a Foreach Loop Container I'd rather provide the recordset as a parameter to the Script Task and do the loop inside the script - this should make it easier for you to pass the data to the REST service call (and process the resulting ID).

Comment: Many thanks Filburt. Its nice proposal. I must admit here, that I'm not brilliant at Scripting C# codes but yes, if I can try and implement it with little resources. Can you/someone guide me to locations/pages/books where I can read and try to implement this?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136025.aspx) should provide you a head start and there should be lots C# examples online for accessing a REST service so you should be able to get it to work. Just update your question if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: I guess you are populating an object variable with you Execute SQL Task? If so you can create an SSIS variable for each of your paremeters and map these up in your For Each Loop, you can then pass the SSIS variables into your Script task.